# Cannot scheduling script in Big query without having to define destination table

Tags: google-bigquery

I wrote the script in standard SQL that included declaring several variables and using loop to replace data in multiple tables and set it to be scheduled query in Big query. Before google updated the UI, I wasn't required to specify destination table so it worked just fine but after google changed its UI, It's required to define destination for query results or else the scheduled query cannot be created.

I tried creating scheduled query with destination table then It has this error message

**'configuration.query.destinationTable cannot be set for scripts'**

I read this document https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries
and it states that scripting query wasn't supposed to have destination table but it seems like google has changed it and now there's no option to not define destination dataset.

Is there anybody currently facing the same problem or have any solution to this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem. When I rolled back the last UI update the problem was fixed. You can go back to the old version by clicking the "Hide Preview Features" button in the bar at the top of the screen.